# Disable Previous Dates When Using Pickadate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, pickadate

I am using [piackadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) as a date picker for my site. I would like to implement the functionality that would disable any previous date. I read the [docs on disabling dates](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#disable-dates) but I don't see a way to disable all previous dates.

How would one do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
var yesterday = new Date((new Date()).valueOf()-1000*60*60*24);

$('#test').pickadate({
  disable: [
    { from: [0,0,0], to: yesterday }
  ]
});
```

`1000*60*60*24` is the number of milliseconds in a day.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/kdoo53vg/

Comment: Thank You! I knew it was something like that but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 28):

You can do it much easier. It will disable all the previous dates.

```
$('#test').pickadate({
    min: true
});
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution

Comment: Concise solution!